# Get last value BEFORE the timerange specified

Tags: sql, oracle

Say, I have a simple table in Oracle that looks like this:

```
Timestamp            TagName          TagValue
----------------------------------------------
2019.11.07 00:05:11  Tag1             1.0
2019.11.07 00:05:12  Tag1             11.2
2019.11.07 00:05:35  Tag2             23.0
2019.11.07 00:06:36  Tag1             0.56
2019.11.07 00:06:11  Tag2             23.6
2019.11.07 00:07:56  Tag2             11.2
2019.11.07 00:08:01  Tag1             123.05
2019.11.07 00:22:35  Tag2             8.13
```

The table keeps 3 years worth of data and some tags change often and some very rarely.

I need to query all "Tag1" rows for a particular timerange but I also need to get the LAST "Tag1" value BEFORE my timerange.

Something like this is easy enough to give me all "Tag1" changes withing the timerange (2019.11.07 00:06:00 - 2019.11.07 00:07:00):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE
  Tagname LIKE 'Tag1'
AND
  (TS BETWEEN
      to_timestamp('2019.11.07 00:06:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
  AND
      to_timestamp('2037.11.07 00:07:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
  )
```

But is there somehow a way to also get the LAST Tag1 change BEFORE the range? So in this case, I need to get this row:
2019.11.07 00:05:12  Tag1             11.2
(in reality this row can be few seconds before or a few months before, or maybe even not existing at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is the use of a subquery and get the maximum timestamp lower than your starting time and use this in your outer query. Additional use of NVL will give desired data if no such record exists:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE
  Tagname = 'Tag1'
AND
  (TS BETWEEN
      NVL((SELECT MAX(TS) FROM MyTable
           WHERE Tagname = 'Tag1'
             AND TS < to_timestamp('2019.11.07 00:06:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')))
          ,to_timestamp('2019.11.07 00:06:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'))
  AND
      to_timestamp('2037.11.07 00:07:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
  )
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So basically I have to dynamically "expand" my timerange and move my "start time" to the time "Tag1" was changed last (obtained by the subquery). Tested and works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LEAD` analytical function as following:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT LEAD(T.TS) OVER(
                PARTITION BY T.TAG -- REMOVE "PARTITION BY" CLAUSE IF YOU ALWAYS  WANT TO WORK WITH SINGLE TAG 
                ORDER BY T.TS ) AS L_TS,
            T.* 
        FROM MYTABLE T
        WHERE T.TAGNAME = 'Tag1'
    )
WHERE
    ( TS BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2019.11.07 00:06:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
         AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2037.11.07 00:07:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') )
    OR ( L_TS BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2019.11.07 00:06:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
              AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2037.11.07 00:07:00.000000', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is brilliant.
Took me a while to get my head around analytical functions never used them before) but it works like a charm.

Moreover, it actually allows me to get these additional values not only for one tagname but for any number of them. Superb, thank you!

Comment: @n_lev . . . Using `lead()` or `lag()` is a much better approach than a subquery.

Comment: Would be really heavy for the database? E.g. if I use lead() over 3 years worth of data with 3 billion records, how bad would it load Oracle? Are we talking 20 seconds before I get the results or 3 hours?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so.